# Equivalent of cmd's "where" in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I can't seem to find anything about a Powershell equivalent of the `where` command from `cmd`. Should I just call it from `cmd` or is there something more elegant in PS?

Comment: Interesting reading I found sometime back on Where.exe and Get-ChildItem: https://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/24/weekend-scripter-where-exe-the-what-why-and-how.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 287):

Use the [`Get-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849711.aspx) commandlet passing it the name of the executable. It populates the Path property of the returned object (of type [ApplicationInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.applicationinfo%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX)) with the fully resolved path to the executable.

```
# ~> (get-command notepad.exe).Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
```

Comment: If you find yourself using this a lot, you can abbreviate the command as `gcm` instead of typing the whole `Get-Command` word every time

Comment: `Source` works the same, see [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1569151/245595)

Answer (score 73):

If you're just looking to have the same functionality without invoking cmd, you can call `where.exe` from powershell, as long as `C:\Windows\System32` is in your path. The command `where` (without the .exe) is aliased to `Where-Object`, so just specify the full name.

```
PS C:\Users\alec> where
cmdlet Where-Object at command pipeline position 1
...

PS C:\Users\alec> where.exe
The syntax of this command is:

WHERE [/R dir] [/Q] [/F] [/T] pattern...
```

Answer (score 64):

`where` isn't a built in `cmd` command. It's a standalone application (`where.exe`), so strictly speaking PowerShell doesn't "need a replacement".

So why doesn't `where` work in PowerShell? It seems to do nothing:

```
PS C:\> where where
PS C:\>
```

By default `where` is aliased to a built-in PS cmdlet.

```
PS C:\> get-help where

NAME
    Where-Object
...
ALIASES
    where
    ?
```

---

Well, that's great to know, but is there a way to avoid calling `where-object` when trying to call `where.exe`?

The answer is, yes.

**Option 1**

Call `where.exe` with extension. (This is a handy way to work around other aliasing and file-extension prioritisation issues.)

```
PS C:\> where.exe where
C:\Windows\System32\where.exe
```

**Option 2**

Remove the alias.

```
PS C:\> Remove-Item alias:\where -Force
PS C:\> where where
C:\Windows\System32\where.exe
```

---

**Side Notes**

[zdan's answer](https://superuser.com/a/676107/142759) proposes using `Get-Command` as an alternative. Although it's a little more verbose (even when using the default `gcm` alias), it has richer functionality than `where.exe`. If used in scripting, do pay attention to the subtle differences between the two. E.g. `where.exe` returns all matches, whereas `Get-Command` returns only the first result unless you include the optional `-TotalCount` parameter.

```
PS C:\> where.exe notepad
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
PS C:\> (gcm notepad).Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
PS C:\> (gcm notepad -TotalCount 5).Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe
PS C:\>
```

And finally, if you remove the default `where` alias, you might also consider reassigning that as an alias to `Get-Command`. (But this would probably be of dubious benefit.)

```
PS C:\> Set-Alias where Get-Command
PS C:\> where notepad

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     notepad.exe                                        10.0.15... C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe


PS C:\> (where notepad).Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
PS C:\>
```

Comment: `(gcm some_program -All).Path` replicates the default behavior of `where.exe`

Answer (score 7):

`Get-ChildItem C:\SomeDir -Recurse *.dll`

That's pretty much what the old where.exe does... was there more specific functionality that you're trying to mimic?

Edit: In response to Joshua's comment... oh, you want to search your PATH environment variables too?  No problem.

```
Foreach($_ In $Env:Path -Split ';')
{
    Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse *.dll
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Who had this idea to define aliases so that you can not call system executables present in PATH?

Anyways, most reliable solution would be, to define an alias, I am used to:

```
PS H:\> Set-Alias which where.exe
PS H:\> which notepad
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
PS H:\>
```

Comment: To set a permanent alias, add it to your PowerShell profile.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go. And you can just add the alias to the master powershell profile, which is found in the variable $profile . I use Notepad++ to edit that and add the alias at the end. Just type in Powershell command line: notepad++ $profile

and add the alias there (here I too went with "which"): Set-Alias which where.exe

Answer (score 4):

Both `Path` and `Source` from `Get-Command` work the same

```
> (Get-Command notepad).Path
C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
> (Get-Command notepad).Source
C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
```